# How to visualize simulations in drake - a generic example

Tags: c++, installation, drake, visualizer, meshcat

I installed drake (tried both from apt and compiler from source) and then **i want to to run some examples** in order to start learning the software. (I have some-experience because i have run some notebooks in pydrake). However, the some examples that also include visualization do not seem to work.

## What i want:

A working simple example that uses either `drake-visualizer` or `meldis` and `meshcat`, written in **C++**, to

1. Completely test my installation and
2. then use it as a *standard practice* to build my own simulations and learn drake.  (Like [ros tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials))

## What i have tried:

### Apt installation - 1st way:

1. I followed [these](https://drake.mit.edu/apt.html#stable-releases) instructions to install a pre-compiled version of drake. (Apart from updating my `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environmental variables).
2. I downloaded [drake-external-examples](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/main) to test my installation. I compiled and run the `drake_cmake_installed_apt` examples, and **all the tests passed**.
3. Then, as i wanted to test visualization, I built `drake_cmake_installed` that contains the example of `uniformly_accerated_particle`. Here one test failed. The output is:

```bash
Running tests...
Test project /home/papaveneti/drake2/drake_examples/drake_cmake_installed/build
    Start 1: import_all_test
1/6 Test #1: import_all_test ..................   Passed    0.35 sec
    Start 2: find_resource_example
2/6 Test #2: find_resource_example ............   Passed    0.02 sec
    Start 3: find_resource_example_py
3/6 Test #3: find_resource_example_py .........   Passed    0.11 sec
    Start 4: particle_test
4/6 Test #4: particle_test ....................   Passed    0.02 sec
    Start 5: simple_bindings_test
5/6 Test #5: simple_bindings_test .............***Failed    0.21 sec
    Start 6: simple_continuous_time_system
6/6 Test #6: simple_continuous_time_system ....   Passed    0.02 sec

83% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 6

Total Test time (real) =   0.72 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      5 - simple_bindings_test (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [Makefile:84: test] Error 8
```

But from what i understant, the problem is that the module `simple_bindings` that is created in the example, isn't being found during the execution of `simple_bindings.py`. So, this doesn't affect the visualiazation.

Then, i run:

```bash
$ /opt/drake/bin/drake-visualizer & ( cd src/particles/ && exec ./uniformly_accelerated_particle)
```

and i get an empty window:
[image: drake_visualization]

### Apt installation - 2nd way:

I did the same steps, but before building and running the examples, I run:

```bash
 export PATH="/opt/drake/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"
  export PYTHONPATH="/opt/drake/lib/python$(python3 -c 'import sys; print("{0}.{1}".format(*sys.version_info))')/site-packages${PYTHONPATH:+:${PYTHONPATH}}"
```

I got exactly the same results.

### Source installation:

I had the same results, while trying to run the same examples. (I think the python bindings were succesful, but i have since uninstalled it).

### extra

1. OS:  ubuntu 20.04 LTS
2. I want to use cmake (not bazel) in order to use drake alongside ros1 in the future (after i have learned the basics of drake).
3. I want to use the C++ version of drake.

Answer (score 0):

The file [atlas_run_dynamics.cc](https://github.com/RobotLocomotoion/drake/blob/master/examples/atlas/atlas_run_dynamics.cc) is an OK demo for that purpose.  You can copy that file to your project, build, and run it:

```
add_executable(atlas_run_dynamics atlas_run_dynamics.cc)
target_link_libraries(atlas_run_dynamics drake::drake)
```

It adds visualization of the simulation by calling `visualization::AddDefaultVisualization(&builder);`, which is the canonical way to visualize to `drake-visualizer` and/or `meldis`.

By default, it runs faster than realtime so I suggest running with `--simulator_target_realtime_rate=1` to slow it down.

See also [drake-ros](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros) which offers a way to visualize a Drake simulation using RViz.

---

p.s. Sorry that the particles was broken.  We intended to [delete that example code](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/17649#issuecomment-1785903495) but forgot to delete all of the copies.

Comment: is there an example that uses  cmake as a building tool,  that has visualization?

Comment: There's nothing exactly what on point, but CMake code is the obvious two-line thing (edited into the answer above now).